# Giving Warnings while segmenting video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, libavcodec

I have a camera stream which gives a video at **10 fps**, resolution with **800x600** with **h264** encoding. I like to split the video into 10 min clips and save it with the system time as its name. 
I use the following code to do so.

```
ffmpeg -i $URL -c copy -map 0 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_atclocktime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 600 -segment_format mp4 %Y%m%d_%H%M%S.mp4
```

But when I'm running the code, it is giving me the following warning.

> [segment @ 0x55968f393e80] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
>
> [segment @ 0x55968f393e80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

And the videos its saving are not exactly 10 minutes in length.

How I can fix those warnings and save the videos with length equals exactly 10 minutes.

Thank You!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: @Will I have seen similar type of questions in stackoverflow before. May be you try to close them first..

Comment: I'm back from combing through the 6m+ questions here, having cast approximately 874k close votes. This is still off topic.

Comment: @Will Yeah.. I just read the information of the topic `FFMPEG` and realized this question is off the topic. Sorry for being rude :)

Comment: NP, and cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ignore the timestamp warnings. H264 streams don't have timestamps so ffmpeg will have to generate them.

Due to keyframe placement, you can't get exact segment length without re-encoding.

Comment: So you saying there is nothing I need to worry about here..?

Comment: Generally, no. But some h264 streams have complex sequence of b frames, and for those, timestamp generation is buggy. In that case you should use mp4box to generate mp4 first